# Photo float wrong when i take a a photo and pass it in ImageView?

Tags: android

i have a button and when click, open camera take photo,the photo save in the sdcard and when i pass it in image view float right i cant understand why, can anybody help please,i want to display the photo with the Height and weight i have in ImageView from layout and only with the camera 2 work with the camera one does work i mean the photo is saved but not display in the image view the code is here

```
Button takePhoto;
ImageView photo;
static final int Cam_Request = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    photo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto);
    takePhoto = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPhoto);
    takePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File file = getFile();
            camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(file));
            startActivityForResult(camera_intent,Cam_Request);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String path = "sdcard/camera_app/image.jpg";
    photo.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
}

private File getFile()
{
    File folder = new File("sdcard/camera_app");
    if (!folder.exists())
    {
        folder.mkdir();
    }
    File image = new File(folder,"image.jpg");

    return image;
}
```

}

Comment: Post your code. Nobody can guess your code and help you

Comment: i have complete my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)                                     
              {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


             imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo)
        }}}
```

Comment: is not this what i want this is for icon not for a real size and second this is not clear i mean with this the app crashet

Comment: I'm not clear about what you are saying. Please speak in English atleast

Comment: im sorry for my language , anyways i have solve my problem ,